# How can I fix "Size Limit Exceeded" for my Apple Watch app?

Tags: swift, app-store-connect, xcode8, apple-watch

Every time I try to submit an update for my app, I get this error:

[image]

I have literally removed all assets from the app except for the .Swift files, storyboard, and the plists. So I know for a fact that the app is not more than 50MB. Yet, I continue to get this error, no matter what else I remove from the app.

I have restarted Xcode, restarted my Mac, changed the build number, removed assets, and nothing is changing.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Do you images of any kind?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Initially I did have 10 icons (all very tiny) but I removed them to troubleshoot and I am still having the issue.

Comment: From watchOS4 size increased by 25MB, so now watch app size limit is 75MB instead of old 50MB https://stackoverflow.com/a/46347141/3759429

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I emailed Apple and they helped me to find the problem. My watchOS app was configured to have duplicate copies of the Swift runtime libraries, one in the watchOS app, and another copy in the watchOS app extension.

I had to go to the extension's project settings, and set **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** to **No**.

Comment: Thank you! Been going mad for a few hours before I finally decided to look and find this.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my time!

Comment: Thanks a lot dude after two days i got your solutions :)

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!

Comment: From watchOS4 size increased by 25MB, so now watch app size limit is 75MB instead of old 50MB https://stackoverflow.com/a/46347141/3759429